# Bootstrap 3 Grid: Responsive Position Absolute Bottom Width Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I need to position an element at the bottom of a container which is using the Bootstrap grid.

The issue I'm having is that the anchor is spanning outside of the parent width. I need the anchor to span 100% and remain within the width of the parent div `content-wrapper`.

I need to keep the 15px padding on each side of the button that comes from the parent container.

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="content-wrapper col-xs-12">
  <div class="content">
    <a class="button" href="#">See more</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39343/) to see the issue in action.

Comment: Bootstrap adds 15px margin in both sides, try whether loading your custom css after boostrap, using `!important` or fixing `margin` to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added `row` class and `container-fluid` class over your HTML structure along with some CSS changes. 
The class `container-fluid` was not working with your import bootstrap. so I have added it additionally in HTML part for your reference.

By this changes, you can achieve the desired result with `15px` gap as mentioned above with default bootstrap structure.

Here is the working code:

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
/* @import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'); */

.content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: gray;  
}
.content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.button {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="content-wrapper col-xs-12">
  <div class="content">
    <a class="button" href="#">See more</a> 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `left:0` to your `.button` class

```
.button {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: That's worked - however, I need to maintain the 15px gaps on each side?

Comment: Just add `margin: 0 15px` to parent div of .button if that's not exactly what you want you can create another div above button and use it as relative position for your absolute button.

Comment: Something like this? I had to put on a height so that the element knows where to do show to the bottom of the parent div: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39346/

Comment: As far as I can see you are using bootstrap so if you make a div with class container it will have margin on right and left then just add your absolute div to that div.

Comment: @Filth I made codepen for you https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVPMeV   Is this what you wanted ?